# How to create a odoo javascript (Odoo Module System) in odoo 17

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-17

The following modules failed to load because of an error, you may find more information in the devtools console:
swm_reports.swm_reports

while creating odoo js in odoo 17

```js
odoo.define('swm_reports.swm_reports', [], function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');

    var MyCustomAction = AbstractAction.extend({
        // Your custom code here
        start: function () {
            // Initialization logic for your action
            console.log("My custom action started!");
        },
    });

    // Register your custom action
    core.action_registry.add('my_custom_action', MyCustomAction);

    return MyCustomAction;

});
```

why im getting this kind of error

Answer (score 0):

The actions were migrated to OWL and they removed the legacy code. You can do the same and migrate your code to OWL

***Example:***

```
/* @odoo-module */

import { Component } from "@odoo/owl";
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";

export class MyCustomAction extends Component {
    // static template = "my_custom_template";
    // Your custom code here
    setup() {
        // Initialization logic for your action
        console.log("My custom action started!");
    }
};

// Register your custom action
registry.category("actions").add("my_custom_action", MyCustomAction);
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I appreciate the guidance. I'll proceed with migrating my code to OWL and removing the legacy code. If I have any further questions, I'll reach out. Thanks again!

Comment: i need to create a page using template and js client action for that im getting "No operation made on this lot." display in the view

Comment: Update the question with the minimal template code to reproduce the error.

Comment: sure,
how to use js(event) and start function in owl

odoo 16 code (FYI)
let ExpenseReportMonthWise = AbstractAction.extend({
  template: "ExpenseReportsMonthTemplate",
  events: {
   "click #search": "button_clicked"
  },
  start: function() {
      
   });
  },
  button_clicked: function() {
      let self = this;

      });
        }
 });
core.action_registry.add('ExpenseReportMonthWise', ExpenseReportMonthWise);

Comment: Did you migrate to OWL?

Comment: Is there a tool or any automated process available for migrating Owl, or do I need to perform the migration manually?

Does Owl provide any built-in mechanism for handling events or actions?

Comment: You can check the owl [GitHub](https://github.com/odoo/owl) repository for further information